# Angular Datapicker don't pass value through NgModel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

i have a page with a form that works as a filter search and one of fields is a date field.

I configured the angular ui date (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date) and the calendar works when i focus the date field.

The problem is:

When i try submit the form, the date field value don't pass to controller through of ng-model, but the other fields works. If i remove ui-date from input, works too.

What i'm doing wrong?

MY HTML

```
<form novalidate name="filterForm" ng-submit="submitFiltro()">
<label class="painel-datas-text" for="field-5">Product</label>
<input class="painel-data-select w-input" id="field-5" maxlength="256" ng-model="filtro.produto" name="produto" placeholder="NET / CLARO" required="required" type="text">

<label class="painel-datas-text" for="field">Date</label>
<input ui-date class="painel-data-select w-input" id="field" maxlength="256" ng-model="filtro.de" name="date" placeholder="01/02/2016" required="required" type="text">

<label class="painel-datas-text" for="field-2">seller</label>
<input class="painel-data-select w-input" id="field-2" maxlength="256" ng-model="filtro.vendedor" name="vendedor" placeholder="TODOS" required="required" type="text">

<input class="painel-button w-button" type="submit" value="FILTRAR">
```

MY JS:

```
var app = angular.module('painelvendas', ['ui.date']);
app.controller('painelController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.submitFiltro = function(){
        console.log($scope.filtro);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen from the documentation, you are not supposed to set the type of the input where you are going to use the directive.